# How do I make containers that trisects a page vertically in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, containers, antd

I want to make a UI using Ant design that is trisects the browser vertically, and will flex to fit to the edges of the browser. I don't want to use two siders and content in the middle because I will be displaying user inputs in the siders, and I don't think the sider component is appropriate for that.

The code sample below will trisect the screen horizontally, while the one below that works similarly to what I want.

```html
<Layout>
    <Content><p>Section 1</p></Content>
    <Content><p>Section 2</p></Content>
    <Content><p>Section 3</p></Content>
<Layout>
```

```html
<Layout>
    <Sider><p>Section 1</p></Sider>
    <Content><p>Section 2</p></Content>
    <Sider><p>Section 3</p></Sider>
<Layout>
```

Am I wrong about my hesitation to use siders, or how do I do it?

Comment: It's easy to do using `flex` css, or you consider only true antd solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it be in a row, and trisect, you can use css like so.

```html
<Layout style = {{display:'flex', flex-direction: 'row'}}>
    <Content className = 'trisect' ><p>Section 1</p></Content>
    <Content className = 'trisect' ><p>Section 2</p></Content>
    <Content className = 'trisect' ><p>Section 3</p></Content>
<Layout>
```

```css
.trisect{
width:33%;
}
```